# How does Cardano Halving work?

Tags: cardano-cli

Does Cardano Halving work similar to Bitcoin Halving? The next Bitcoin halving is projected to take place in March 2024, will Cardano Halving happen the same year?

The Cardano price prediction for 2023 (by coinpedia) with an extended bullish trend is to $1.1308, Will the Halving event effect this price prediction?

Answer (score 5):

Cardano's ***staking*** and Bitcoin's ***mining*** are built on completely different principles. Cardano [staking rewards](https://medium.com/the-capital/cardano-911-twenty-interesting-facts-about-cardano-6e165914d1e8) gradually get reduced by `0.2...0.3%` every 5 days (One Epoch), whereas the reward for creating a new block in Bitcoin is [halved every 4 years](https://medium.com/geekculture/cryptocurrency-911-what-are-miners-really-doing-1a1b816bdc83).

Answer (score 0):

Cardano does not have a halving. Available rewards per block decrease gradually, not stepwise as in Bitcoin.